# Creating vector of primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, c++11, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Please review my Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation.

```
std::vector<int> generate(const int& n) {
    std::vector<bool> input(n+1, true);
    for (int i = 2; i * i<= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; i*j <= n    ; ++j) {
            input[i*j] = false;
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> primes{};
    for (auto i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (input[i]) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

How can I improve and make this faster?

Comment: Note: `std::vector<bool>` is specialized and does not conform to normal container semantics. It is specifically optimized for size and as such has very poor speed characteristics. You may want to try `std::vector<char>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Wikipedia, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm is:

> To find all the prime numbers less than or equal to a given integer n
>   by Eratosthenes' method:
>
> 1. Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through n: (2, 3, 4,
>      ..., n).
> 2. Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
> 3. Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in increments of p, and mark them in the list (these will be 2p, 3p,
>      4p, etc.; the p itself should not be marked).
> 4. **Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now
>      equal this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from
>      step 3.**

Your algorithm does not seem right really, notably it skips the step 4 which is essential for fast operation; and there are some non-C++ idioms too

- <s>Do not return the std::vector; instead pass it as a reference to the function.</s>
- Do not pass integers as const references.
- If n < 2, return empty vector.
- The Eratosthenes sieve goes like: "for all values from 2 to sqrt(n) - if the number is a prime *then* mark all its multiples not prime. However all multiples less than i * i have been marked already composite by previous iterations.
- Do not multiply the loop variables when a simple addition suffices.
- As a simple optimization, the 2 is always in the primes as we skipped the "no values" already; thus we add it. Then we iterate only odd integers starting from 3.

Thus we get

```
std::vector<int> generate(int n) {
    std::vector<int> result = std::vector<int>();
    if (n < 2) {
        return result;
    }

    // initialize the vector
    std::vector<bool> input(n + 1, true);

    // calculate the upper limit as the square root of
    // of N. all composite numbers <= N must have a 
    // factor <= sqrt(N)
    int sqrtN = (int)sqrt(n);

    // iterate from 2 up to the square root of N
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrtN; i ++) {
        if (! input[i]) {
            // i is a proven composite number,
            // all its multiples have been 
            // marked not prime by all its prime factors by now.
            continue;
        }

        // as an optimization, all multiples *less* than 
        // the square of i are already marked, (they have 
        // another prime factor less than i), so we can start
        // from the square which is the smallest composite
        // not yet marked
        for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i) {
            input[j] = false;
        }
    }

    // as n >= 2, then add 2 here
    result.push_back(2);

    // and check only odd numbers here,
    // no other even number can be set
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (input[i]) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course you do not need the second loop to just fill in the result vector; if the `input[i]` is true (the `continue` was not executed), the number is a prime and you can `push_back` it to the `result` vector there:

```
if (! input[i]) {
    // i is an already proven composite number,
    // all its multiples have been 
    // marked not prime by all its prime factors by now.
    continue;
}

// i is a prime
result.push_back(i);
```

Comment: thanks for the code. Can you explain your answer?

Comment: The return value optimization should be able to deal with the returned vector just fine. Even if it does not, move semantics shoud deal with it anyway. There is no need to pass the returned vector as a reference.

Comment: As an additional optimization, there is no need to store any even values in the vector, though this would be minimal savings anyhow considering that a vector of integers is later created.

Comment: "Do not pass integers as const references" why?

Comment: Can you explain "Do not pass integers as const references" further? Why shouldn't I do that? I thought a user might sometimes prefer writing generate(390); than int x = 390; generate(x);

Comment: Just pass an int by value here. (You could pass by non-const reference as an out parameter, leaving aside whether out parameters are good.) Then `generate(390);` is fine. Passing by reference is to save needless copying of structs/classes. It's as much work to pass a pointer to an int and then dereference it, as just to copy it—probably more work, although I have often wondered if compilers optimize const-reference passing of primitive types into pass-by-value. If they can tell there is no casting-away-const, that should be safe.

Comment: If you are never going to test even numbers then no point removing multiples of `2`. Start with `3` and move up from there. One extra optimization is to increment by 2 then 4 in your final loop. This is the equivalent of excluding 2 and 3 from your loop.

Comment: Also compress the map so that only odd values are stored in the map...

Comment: In addition, I would replace each occurrence of `push_back` with `emplace_back`. Also, `int sqrtN` can be and thus should be `const`. Many hand-written loops could be replaced with standard algorithms too, but maybe this is unnecessary nitpicking already.

Answer (score 3):

Taking @Antti Haapala as a starting point. Two small optimizations.

```
- for (int i = 2; i <= sqrtN; i ++) {
+ for (int i = 5; i <= sqrtN; i ++) {

  result.push_back(2);
+ result.push_back(3);

- for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
+ for (int i = 5, jump = 2; i <= n; i += jump, jump = 4 - jump) {
```

The optimization is that you can ignore all values that are multiples of 2 and 3 if you increment by 2 then 4 then 2 then 4 etc...

Now that you know that you are already ignoring multiples of 2 and 3 in your second loop; then in your first loop you don't need to even check for anything below 5. Just make sure to add 3 to the final result.

Comment: In the first loop start at 5 too and increment by jump. There is no point in marking multiples of 2 and 3 if you later never use them. Marking multiples of 2 and 3 takes the longest as they are the most of them so that realy helps.

Answer (score 2):

#### Nitpickish stuff:

1. You have no input validation, negative n results in an empty result set.
2. When generating the primes I think using the post-increment would be more obvious

   ```
   for (auto i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
   ```

   I take that you want to benefit from the minimal performance increase, but that's more premature optimization, and thus IMO unncessary..
3. Your second for-loop isn't spaced properly:
   It should be:

   ```
   for (int j = i; i * j <= n; ++j) {
   ```

#### Less nitpickish stuff:

- The code's logic for eliminating primes is non-obvious. The first thing I thought when I saw your prime-sieve was. "Wouldn't this also cross out 2?". Your code could use a comment here and there ;)
- **1 is not a prime!** Since you initialize your input to all true and start reading out at 1, you'll have 1 in the resulting primes.
- A vector can't have a negative amount of elements. As soon as `n < -2` you might get problems when initializing. I wouldn't know since I don't do C++, but eh.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two loops. If it is set up correctly, every time you test a new number, if it is still `true`, you can output it immediately. And if it is false, *you can skip crossing out its multiples*. They have already been set to `false` earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You mark multiples of pimes in the seive with:

```
for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i) {
    input[j] = false;
}
```

Say i = 5 then you mark 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60 ...

You might notice that every second number is a multiple of 2. No need to mark them since they are never tested for inclusion later on. So use `j += 2 * i`.

If you use the trick to skip multiples of 2 and 3 then you can use that here too, advancing by `2 * i` and `4 * i` alternatively. But you have to compute with which one to start. Actually I would advance by `6 * i` and set input[j] and input[j - 2 * i]. This time you have to compute the right starting point (`i * i` or `(i + 2) * i`) instead of the right step.

---

I also have another idea in mined that i always wanted to try and benchmark.
In the current code you start by creating a seive of the full size and fully initialize it. Then you mark off multiples of primes. The above answeres already eliminated a lot of duplicate marking but I think one can do better.

Note: There is no need to store even numbers in the seive but it's easier to explain things with them in it. Compressing the seive to skip even numbers is left as exercise.

Start with a seive of `2 * 3 * 5 = 30` and mark it as before (mark `5 * 5 = 25`). The next prime is 7. Grow the seive to `2 * 3 * 5 * 7 = 210`. The first 30 entries are copied repeadately to fill the seive. Then mark 7. The next prime is 11. Grow the seive to `2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 = 2310`, again by copying the first 210 entries. For every prime you find you grow the seive up to the final size you need, which should happen quickly (max 27 for 32bit, 47 for 64bit systems).

Using memcpy to grow the seive could be faster than initializing it at start and the loops to mark individual multiples of primes. It only helps for the first few primes but those are the ones with the most work.